# How can I set up buttons to call different using jQuery, AJAX, JSON and MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to have a screen something like that below:

```
   <div id="statusText></div> 

   <button type="button" id="transferData1"
       data-href="/Tools/Data/TransferData1">Transfer Data 1</button>
   <button type="button" id="transferData2"
       data-href="/Tools/Data/TransferData2">Transfer Data 2</button>
   <button type="button" id="transferData3"
       data-href="/Tools/Data/TransferData3">Transfer Data 3</button>
```

Where each button when clicked will call an MVC action method and then have it return some status. Is there a simple way that I can set this up with jQuery, Ajax and JSON when I have multiple buttons?

I have the following script so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#transferData')
            .click(function () {
                xxx
            });

    });
</script>
```

But how could I make this script work for different button IDs and also call different action methods with Ajax?

Comment: what do you mean from simple way? you don't need a form to call action links.

Comment: I am hoping to do this with jQuery but not really familiar with how it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of options

1) use a form, give each button a value and differentiate which button was pushed server side by looking at the value posted back for that button. There's a a nice way to clean this up/split into multiple server side actions by using ActionFilters (http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=724).  If it needs to be ajax then you could use the unobtrusive ajax extensions in mvc3.

2) use jquery to override the click method of the buttons, call the action manually then use the result

```
$('[data-href]').click(function() { 
  $.ajax({ url: $(this).attr('data-href') })
    .success(function(data) {});
});
```

Comment: I like the second method very much. I didn't realize it was possible to use data-href as a selector. The idea I had was something much more complicated. Would it be possible to modify the selector so that for example only buttons that are inside the div with an id of "actions" had this click method?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know the procedure then i think that the most simplest and appropriate way is to bind each button to the form if you want to post some values as well otherwise no need to have it. form1 for button1 form2 for button2 and form3 for button3 . the things should be easy from there.

have a jquery button click event for each of the button, have a single action method,  pass the button name to the action method and according to the button name you can process the request and return the json result.